# change color saturation of scale_fill_gradient2 (ggplot)

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors

In continuation of the [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37702607/smooth-2d-surface)  I am trying to depict 2D surface using ggplot. The colors are determined by `scale_fill_gradient2`, however they are too bright and dull when the values are close to 0 (white color). I have tried `scale_colour_hue` to change saturation, but it doesnot work.

[image]

```
names(plot2d) <- c("x", "y", "z")
      ggplot(plot2d) + aes(x, y, z = z, fill = z)  + geom_tile(aes(fill = z)) +
        scale_fill_gradient2(limits=c(-40, 40), "height",
                             low=rgb(0,255,0, maxColorValue = 255), mid = "white",
                             high=rgb(255,0,0,  maxColorValue = 255), guide="colorbar") + 
        geom_raster(interpolate=TRUE) + geom_contour(color = "white", alpha = 0.5) 

     # + scale_colour_hue(h=c(180, 270))
```

Comment: Probably not relevant to your question, but why are you using geom_tile and geom_raster? Does your data span the full range set by limits?

Comment: You know this isn't a colour blind friendly fill don't you?

Comment: I included the link to prev. topic to show that I am smoothing surface. That is why I need geom_raster

Comment: No, the data span the full range set only partly but I think that it is possible to somehow change saturation of the colors

Comment: Sure, you need geom_raster, but do you also need geom_tile

Comment: you are right, I do not need it

Comment: use different colors in the gradient? why do you need white as the mid color? alternatively use a gradient that is not linear.

Comment: @Henrik, you made my day! That is what I was looking for